# ruta estatica no funciona

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

lo hago sencillo, estoy creando una ruta estática pero cuando accedo a una imagen que tengo guardada en esa carpeta me devuelve un 404, no entiendo por que, les dejo mi codigo

```
class Server {

  private app: Application

  constructor() {
    this.app = express()
    this._Config()
    this._Routes()
  }

 private _Config(): void {
   // Settings
   this.app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
   // middlewares
   this.app.use(morgan('dev'));
   this.app.use(cors());
   this.app.use(express.json());
   this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   this.app.use(passport.initialize());
   this.app.use(helmet());
   this.app.use(compression());
   this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './../uploads')))
   console.log(path.join(__dirname, './../uploads/'))
  }
}

const server = new Server();
server._Start();
```

este codigo esta en la carpeta index.ts, les dejo una imagen de mi directorio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Desde qué directorio estás invocando a tu `index.ts`? No me refiero a dónde está guardado, sino a desde dónde lo llamas.

Comment: el index.ts es e archivo que arranca el servidor, `"main": "./src/index.ts",` asi lo coloque en el package.json

Comment: Intenta con `../uploads`.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar

Comment: El error `http` 401 es de autorización. ¿Puedes poner exactamente el mensaje de error?

Comment: perdon, el error era un 404, ya lo corregi

Comment: Mira esto haber si te ayuda https://expressjs.com/es/starter/static-files.html